# Modding Jquery Photostack Script To Use A Database For Images

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have been using the following script, and im trying to mod it to pull image details from my mysql database. It appears to work, and loads all the albums up , along with the album thumbnail and title, when I click on the album thumb it loads the first image from the gallery, but then no more, all I can see is the next image icon.

This is the original script :
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/27/beautiful-photo-stack-gallery-with-jquery-and-css3/

Iv modded this part of the code to pull the albums from the database :

```
<div id="ps_slider" class="ps_slider">
        <a class="prev disabled"></a>
        <a class="next disabled"></a>
        <div id="ps_albums">
        <?php 
        include("../connect.php");

        $sql = <<<SQL
SELECT *
FROM `albums`
WHERE isalbum='yes'
SQL;
if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
echo '<div id="'.$row['albumid'].'" class="ps_album" style="opacity:0;"><img     src="../albums/'.$row['albumid'].'/albumthumbnail/'.$row['albumthumbnail'].'" alt=""/><div     class="ps_desc"><h2>'.$row['albumname'].'</h2><span></span></div></div>';
}


        ?>
            </div>  
    </div>
```

This part of the code is supposed to load the next image :

```
/**
            * when we click on an album,
            * we load with AJAX the list of pictures for that album.
            * we randomly rotate them except the last one, which is
            * the one the User sees first. We also resize and center each image.
            */
            $ps_albums.children('div').bind('click',function(){
                var $elem = $(this);
                var album_name  = $(this).attr('id');
                var $loading    = $('<div />',{className:'loading'});
                $elem.append($loading);
                $ps_container.find('img').remove();
                $.get('photostack.php', {album_name:album_name} , function(data) {
                    var items_count = data.length;
                    for(var i = 0; i < items_count; ++i){
                        var item_source = data[i];
                        var cnt         = 0;
                        $('<img />').load(function(){
                            var $image = $(this);
                            ++cnt;
                            resizeCenterImage($image);
                            $ps_container.append($image);
                            var r       = Math.floor(Math.random()*41)-20;
                            if(cnt < items_count){
                                $image.css({
                                    '-moz-transform'    :'rotate('+r+'deg)',
                                    '-webkit-transform' :'rotate('+r+'deg)',
                                    'transform'         :'rotate('+r+'deg)'
                                });
                            }
                            if(cnt == items_count){
                                $loading.remove();
                                $ps_container.show();
                                $ps_close.show();
                                $ps_overlay.show();
                            }
                        }).attr('src',item_source);
                    }
                },'json');
            });
```

In the photostack.php I have changed it to the following :

```
<?php
$location   = '../albums';
$location2  = '800x600';
$album_name = $_GET['album_name'];
$files      = glob($location . '/' . $album_name . '/' . $location2 . '/*.    {jpg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
$encoded    = json_encode($files);
echo $encoded;
unset($encoded);
```

So somewhere in that for some reason its pulling in only the first photo out of the album folder and not all of them ?.

In Chrome console I get :

photostack.php?album_name=67016ce16a
/twinfocus/gallery
GET
200
OK
text/html
jquery.min.js:130
Script
273 B
51 B
10 ms
10 ms
10 ms0
loading.gif
/twinfocus/gallery/images
GET
200
OK
image/gif
jquery.min.js:103
Script
(from cache)
Pending
00
01774fa806.jpg
/twinfocus/albums/67016ce16a/800x600
GET
200
OK
image/jpeg
jquery.min.js:48
Script
(from cache)
Pending
00
next_photo.png
/twinfocus/gallery/images
GET
200
OK
image/png
jquery.min.js:118
Script
(from cache)
Pending
00

If I click the next_photo.png the last photo flies off, but no new one comes in, also no more script activity is recorded in the console.

Comment: is it the php or the js at fault?

Comment: Im not sure, the php file appears to be pulling at least one file from the album directory, but for some reason doesnt pull any more in. There is this line $files   = glob($location . '/' . $album_name . '/' . $location2 . '/*.{jpg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
$encoded  = json_encode($files);
in photostack.php, which I presume is pulled in via Ajax, but im not sure how to check what is held in $files, as it should in theory be all the file names in the album directory

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved this !, for some reason the photos in the albums had the extension .jpeg and not .jpg, so im not why where I downloaded them from to get that extension. Anyway, I changed

```
$files      = glob($location . '/' . $album_name . '/' . $location2 . '/*.{jpg,gif,png}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

and added jpeg

```
$files      = glob($location . '/' . $album_name . '/' . $location2 . '/*.{jpg,gif,png,jpeg}', GLOB_BRACE);
```

and now it works perfectly !.